# Can't create instance - Constructor has private access

Tags: java, class, oop, compiler-errors, static

I have tried to create instance of  Desktop Class using
`Desktop desktop = new Desktop();` 
but i get the error `Desktop() has private access in Desktop` 
but In [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) desktop class declared as public.like this..

> public class Desktop
>   extends Object

so since it is public. and neither static. so why cant I create a instance of it? 
I know I can use
 `Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();`
But I cant understand why I cant create a instance of Desktop class.

Comment: You can create an instance, just not directly. You'll have to use the getDesktop() method. The Desktop class is public, it's constructor is private. It's a singleton (or similar construction)

Comment: If you write a class without a constructor, then the compiler adds a *synthetic* no-args constructor. In this case there is a constructor, but it's not public. It's up to the Java library how instances are created - which will probably be one per `AppContext` on demand.

Comment: In the java docs at the top, you will see this line *Summary: Nested | Field | Constr | MethodDetail: Field | Constr | Method*  - if this case the `Constr` is not a link as there are no constructors

Comment: you should show how the constructor (`Desktop()`) is defined. Also, please try to make question titles more generic to be useful for other people as well. Someone might have exactly the same problem with another class not called Desktop ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation:

> The Desktop class allows a Java application to launch associated
>   applications registered on the native desktop to handle a URI or a
>   file.

The `Desktop` objects represents the user's native desktop. It's not a "normal" object that you could create many instances of, because there is only one desktop and it must be linked to many things of the operative system. You shouldn't worry about creating this object. The java libraries will take care of creating this object and hooking it up to the operative system.

This is why you can't create an instance. And the way that developers of this class ensure that you can't create instances of this class is to set the constructor as `private`. That's what the error `Desktop() has private access in Desktop` means.

Answer (score 4):

This message means that the `Desktop()` (the constructor) is private inside the class. If you look at the documentation, you wouldn't find any public constructor that you can use. Hence you need to use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#getDesktop()) static method to create an instance (which is slightly incorrect in your question btw):

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
```